# How to provide parameters to service registered outside services.yaml

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am having an issue with Symfony autowiring.
I need to replace one of third party services with my own.
The service is originally defined like this:

```
    ewz_recaptcha.form.type:
        class: EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType
        public: true
        arguments:
            - '%ewz_recaptcha.public_key%'
            - '%ewz_recaptcha.enabled%'
            - '%ewz_recaptcha.ajax%'
            - '@ewz_recaptcha.locale.resolver'
            - '%ewz_recaptcha.api_host%'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

My definition looks similar:

```
    ewz_recaptcha.form.type:
      class: App\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType
      public: true
      arguments:
          - ''
          - false
          - '%ewz_recaptcha.ajax%'
          - '@ewz_recaptcha.locale.resolver'
          - '%ewz_recaptcha.api_host%'
      tags:
          - { name: form.type }
```

I ignore the first 2 parameters since those are loaded later from database (thats the change I did in the service).

Now this works fine if I put it in `config/services.yaml`
But since in this project I use that file only for project services, and all overwrites I put in third party config files, I tried to move it to `config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml`

But now I am getting error saying:

`Cannot autowire service "App\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType": argument "$publicKey" of method "EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType::__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.`

I even hooked into `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AutowirePass` to check what is going on, and when defined in `services.yaml` the `$arguments` parameter is filled with my arguments, but when moved to `ewz_recaptcha.yaml` arguments array is empty.

Is there a different way I should define arguments when service is defined outside services.yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem most likely is, that `App\Form\Type\EWZRecaptchaType` is being registered in two places by accident. You do it manually in your `config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml` and additionally the psr-4 discover in your `config/services.yaml` will collect it as well.

```
#config/services.yaml
services:
    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

The solution is to add the form type to the excluded classes here to prevent it from being registered, e.g. using something like:

```
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Form/Type/EWZRecaptchaType.php,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Comment: That works, but feels fishy to me.
Shouldnt Symfony ignore the autoload if it has explicit class defined?

Comment: Classes are added per file. `services.yaml` does not know if the services was registered somewhere else. Additionally you will register the service under 2 different names, the classe name in services.yaml and your `ewz_recaptcha.form.type`. Symfony assumes you did this intentionally, but one service is obviously not fully configured. You could also use other solutions like not autowiring that class manually or binding the parameters to every service of that type, but I think my solution is the most straightforward one, when you want both files.

Comment: @HubertNNN - Just out of curiosity, does your working solution still define the service in config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml?  If it works then great but I would not have expected that you could define a service in a bundle config file.  Have you confirmed that you are getting your version of EWZRecaptchaType?